# Determining "by inspection" whether an ODE in a system ever goes to zero

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

This question is motivated by [First Passage Time of Markov Process: Can you spot a mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4558344/first-passage-time-of-markov-process-can-you-spot-a-mistake/4558383#4558383) .

In that question, we have $N$ particles to start. When $n$ particles are present, $nL$ particles disappear per unit time, while there is a rate of $nR$ for the process to immediately stop. Everything is otherwise memoryless, so we can model it as a Markov chain on $N+2$ states, two of which are absorbing.

Since I mentioned that *two* states are absorbing, it is not hard to see that it is possible for the absorption to happen through everything going out the left side, rather than anything going out the right side. One can use the Markov property a bunch of times to conclude that this happens with probability $\left ( \frac{L}{L+R} \right )^N$. Thus the answer to that original question is $+\infty$ and that can be inferred without any detailed analysis.

Where my question arises is after we convert the problem into the system for $Q=P(\tau>t)$ where $\tau$ is the time to stop via exiting out the right (or $+\infty$ if all particles exit out the left). Through a bunch of work with the total probability formula, you get

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=\sum_{n=0}^N -nR p_n Q \\
\frac{dp_n}{dt}=(n+1)L p_{n+1}-nLp_n,n=0,1,\dots,N-1 \\
\frac{dp_N}{dt}=-NLp_N \\
Q(0)=1,p_0(0)=\dots=p_{N-1}(0)=0,p_N(0)=1.$$

In this form I find it non-obvious that $Q$ doesn't go to zero. It is not too hard to see that whether it goes to zero doesn't care what $R$ is in $(0,\infty)$, it only depends on whether $\int_0^\infty \sum_n n p_n(s) ds$ is finite. That doesn't depend on $L$, either. But is it obvious that this integral is finite?

A way of doing it is to note that the eigenvalues are $0,-1,\dots,-N$, and that the eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ is $(1,0,\dots,0)^T$, which contributes to the $n=0$ term only, which does nothing to make $Q$ smaller. Thus all the $p_n$ other than $p_0$ are dominated by some $Ce^{-t}$ so the integral is finite. But this is basically solving the whole system, other than determining some coefficients of the initial condition in terms of eigenvectors.

Is there any more immediate way to see what's happening in systems like this one?